# Cannot change custom UICollectionViewCell in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a `UICollectionView` with custom `UICollectionViewCell`s. I used Interface Builder (via XCode 8) to size the collection view and cells when first making it.

Now, I'm trying to adjust the size of the cells and I'm unable to do so in Interface Builder (using XCode 9). I cannot adjust the width or height of the cells on either the collection view itself or on the custom cell. The up/down arrows don't do anything and neither does typing in a value. It just stays set at 145.

I saw some answers about not being able to do this with a `UICollectionViewController` via Interface Builder, only a `UICollectionView`, but it is a collection view and not `UICollectionViewController`.

I'm sure there's some new setting/config in XCode 9 that I'm missing, but I can't figure out why I can't adjust the custom value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.

Turned out that the item size was defined by the contained flow layout. So editing the item size in the flow layout, and the parent collection view had its item size changed accordingly.

Comment: For me, in `Collection View Flow Layout`, change `Estimate Size` from `automatic` to `custom` do the job, what size I apply to `collection view` is applied to `flow layout` now. Xcode 12.

Answer (score 3):

I tried Jonny's answer, but I use a custom FlowLayout and couldn't edit it's cell size either. I had to manually edit the size of the collection view, the cell and the layout in the storyboard source code (right-click on the storyboard in project view and select "open as / source code").

Now the size is correct but still not editable from the UI  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, width would not change.  But I changed the height to something different and it then let me edit the width.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 12.3. I had the same issue and what fixed it for me was changing the collection view scroll direction from vertical to horizontal to make the change, then obviously reverting back to vertical (my intended direction) once I was done editing the values.